# How can I test broken images using Selenium IDE?

Tags: javascript, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-ide

I saw an example in this [site](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/67-broken-images) that it is possible to test broken images using javascript but the example provided is in Ruby language. 
I'm thinking that I can use the `runScript`command in Selenium IDE and make a javascript code that would detect broken images although I don't know how.

Can someone please provide a code to do this? Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not a usual thing but it is possible.

Check this out:

You can use **verifyEval** command for verifying the result of a javascript code. Also you can use **storeEval** to do some javascript and to retrieve the result and to use it later. Also you can do **getEval** if you want to do javascript only.

So if you would like to fail if there is at least one broken image on the page do:

**Command**

```
verifyEval
```

**Target**

```
var allImg=window.document.getElementsByTagName("img"), i=0, img, result=true;  
while (img = allImg[i++]) 
  {if (img.complete &&  typeof img.naturalWidth != "undefined" && img.naturalWidth > 0) 
    {} 
  else 
    {result=false;}}; 
result;
```

**Value**

```
true
```

Or you can for example mark all the broken\normal images to count them. Here is an example that will fail if more than 5% of images on the page is broken

**Command**

```
getEval
```

**Target**

```
var allImg=window.document.getElementsByTagName("img"), i=0, img;  
while (img = allImg[i++]) 
  {if (img.complete &&  typeof img.naturalWidth != "undefined" && img.naturalWidth > 0) 
    {img.setAttribute('tag','passed');} 
  else 
    {img.setAttribute('tag','broken');}};
```

And then:

```
storeXpathCount | //img                                        | all
storeXpathCount | //img[@tag='broken']                         | broken
verifyEval      | storedVars['broken']*100/storedVars['all']>5 | true
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! this pretty much answered my question.

Comment: Is it possible to turn this into a user-extension js? If so, how would I do that?

Comment: It is possible that's for sure. But that's another question :). Take a look here http://www.codediesel.com/testing/adding-custom-commands-to-the-selenium-ide/

Comment: Or a single element: 
<tr>
 <td>verifyEval</td>
 <td>imgElement = window.document.getElementById('my_id'); imgElement.complete &amp;&amp; imgElement.naturalHeight != 0</td>
 <td>x</td>
</tr>

Where you can use any method to retrieve the element (like getElementByXpath instead of getElementById).